# javascript method not found 'Method Name' is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, onclick, image

I've implemented a simple `JQuery.GetJSON` method on the click of an `<img>` tag. The problem is that Internet explorer is throwing exception that methodname is undefined.

Can anybody guide me on this.

HTML:

```
<div class="itemgenerate">
    <img src="/images/generate.png" onclick="sendJSONRequest()" style="cursor: pointer;" />
</div>
<div id="divTarget" class="itemtext">
    <p id="pStuff"></p>
</div>
```

Java Script:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" />
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function sendJSONRequest() {
        $.getJSON("/Home/Generate", $('#text1').val(), function (data) {
            $('#pStuff').text(data.Stuff);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Please if anybody can explain me what is wrong here:

Comment: try with `onClick="javascript:sendJSONRequest();"`

Comment: I've tried debugging the javascript and it points to the line of the `<img>` tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`script` tags can't be self-closing.  You need a closing `script` tag:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
```

Your current syntax means the first script tag won't be closed and its content will be treated as part of the first.  Since the first tag has a `src` attribute, its content will be ignored, so your function won't be defined.

Comment: I have seen that jquery is loaded. Using this `<body onload="if (jQuery) alert('Success'); else alert('Failure');` and success was the result, you are right in case of XHTML though, but most browsers support finishing the tag this way...

Comment: The issue was resolved because of the above mentioned answer. Although the jQuery was successfully loaded on startup, don't know why? :(

Comment: @Naveed From [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Element/Script): "must have both a start tag and an end tag". I had my answer the wrong way round: jQuery loads, but the content of the tag doesn't.

Comment: Can you please highlight on why the code inside the anonymous method is not firing. i.e., `$('#pStuff').text(data.Stuff);` this line is never executed...

Comment: @Naveed Because code inside a script tag is not executed if the tag has a `src` attribute. Since your first tag is never closed, the contents of the second are considered part of that tag. Nothing within that tag is ever executed.

Comment: thanks for the explanation though. I wanted to ask that now when I've changed the above script tag accordingly. my anonymous lines of code are not firing although `controller` is returning the data in `JSONified` format...

Comment: @Naveed Hard to answer that in the comments section of a different question. If you can't figure it out, you should open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the JQuery way to use `onclick=` in the tag; one of the main points of using JQuery is to allow you to abstract the script code away from the HTML markup. So you would use something like this instead:

```
$(document).ready() {
    $('#myimage').click(sendJSONRequest);
}
```

Comment: @lonesomeday - you're right, not an answer to the actual question. It was too much information to fit into a comment, though. That said, if the problem is in the `<img>` tag as he says, then changing to use this technique may solve the problem.